# curl is installed and working but gives error when i run "php composer.phar install"

Tags: php, curl

I have installed every thing , I am using wamp on my windows 7 
 but when i run command on php composer.phar install

but it give error

Problem 1
    - behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.3 requires fabpot/goutte @dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[dev-master, 1.0.x-dev, v0.1.0, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

```
- behat/mink-goutte-driver dev-master requires fabpot/goutte ~1.0 -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver 1.0.x-dev requires fabpot/goutte ~1.0 -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.0 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.* -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.1 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.2 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.4 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.x@dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.5 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.6 requires fabpot/goutte 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.7 requires fabpot/goutte ~1.0.1 -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.8 requires fabpot/goutte ~1.0.1 -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- behat/mink-goutte-driver v1.0.9 requires fabpot/goutte ~1.0.1 -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

- fabpot/goutte v0.1.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- fabpot/goutte dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- fabpot/goutte v1.0.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- fabpot/goutte v1.0.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- fabpot/goutte v1.0.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- fabpot/goutte v1.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- fabpot/goutte 1.0.x-dev requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

- Installation request for behat/mink-goutte-driver * -> satisfiable by behat/mink-goutte-driver[dev-master, 1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v1.0.5, v1.0.6, v1.0.7, v1.0.8, v1.0.9].
```

cUR is Already Installed and working with other things also show enabled on phpifo();

Any one can help ?

Comment: PHP's `libcurl` differs from the actual cURL. You can either install cURL on your system or use Git Bash to perform this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install PHP curl.. To do that, stop wamp server and 
1. open php.ini in both apachi folder and php folder of wamp(assuming you are using wamp) and un comment extension=php_curl.dll
2. Install curl for windows from [here](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/). 
3. Keep C:\Program Files\cURL\bin in path variable

Note: (please ensure that your C:\Windows\System32 contains "ssleay32.dll" & "libeay32.dll"(if not , copy from PHP dir of wamp.